# The recognition of the word "Enough"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs, determiners

I came across a sentence and had bugged me ever since. I cannot identify whether the word "Enough" is an adjective, a pronoun, a determiner or an adverb although I highly suspect that is an **adjective** since it comes after a **linking verb** and describes the noun; so here it is:

> Even the small amount she had taken was **enough** to warm her throat as it slid down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an **adjective** modifying amount.  It is a quantifier.

It is easier to see here:

"One drink is enough to make me drunk."

or

"There is enough money to buy the book."

Comment: Adjectives and determiners are normally seen as distinct word classes.